# Is == guaranteed to work when comparing objects loaded from NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Here's what we know: It's recommended by NHibernate to override Equals() and GetHashCode(). It's recommended by Microsoft that you NOT override operator == in non-immutable types. It seems, therefore, that client code should not be using operator==  to compare objects. For example, assuming Foo overloads GetHashCode() and Equals correctly, then:

```
var foo1 = session.Get<Foo>(23);

 ...

var foo2 = session.Get<Foo>(23);

Assert.IsTrue( foo1 == foo2 );  // May fail!
Assert.IsTrue( foo1.Equals(foo2)); // Guaranteed!
```

Is this a correct summation?

Comment: Can you link to the Microsoft recommendation? I'm curious. On the other hand, mutability on objects/parts of objects could still cause problems with `Equals` and, more specifically, `GetHashCode`. I wonder what's the additional risk factor with defining `==`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. Does your title mean that you want to know if the *default* `==` operator will always work? Or are you just concerned that even an *overloaded* `==` operator might fail for some strange reason?

Comment: Microsoft recommendation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: @dlev - My question is whether it is safe to compare two objects loaded from NHibernate using operator==.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hibernate session guarantees that both get-calls in your sample code would actually return the same object instance.

So in the case of [persistent](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview) hibernate objects belonging to the same session the == operator would work reliably.

Comment: Can you link to the guarantee? It appears to be failing in my case.

Comment: Have a look at chapter[11.3. Considering object identity](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/transactions.html#transactions-identity).  I used the == operator alot in a hibernate project and it always worked for me as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your summation is correct. Equals() is an equality comparison. With a simple type like a string or an int == is guaranteed to work, but with an object I believe you're better off using Equals().

Answer (score 0):

The equality operator `==` will do an reference equality comparison. E.g. does the reference of `foo1` equal the reference of `foo2`.